# java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key length for DES-EDE3

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic

Running into a strange issue on WebLogic 11g/Linux. After successfully deploying my ear file, some of the functionality fails with the following exception. Using Sun JDK 6. Strange thing is that it works fine on Windows (same jdk version) but fails on Linux.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key length for DES-EDE3: 45 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files so that the JVM will ignore the invalid key length.

Reference: [apache.org](https://cwiki.apache.org/STONEHENGE/installing-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited-strength-jurisdiction-policy-files-6.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried that and it has not worked. Note that if the JCE policy files are an issue, the error would be slightly different. It would say "illegal key size". The error I receive is "invalid key length".